# What lifecycle-events are called in fragments?

Tags: android, database, android-fragments

I have a fragment that displays a list in a recyclerView. When I click on one of the items I want that a new fragment opens. Both those fragments use the same database, so I got my ReadableDatabase in onCreateView and want to close it in onDestroyView. Is that the correct way? 
Also as I don't want that the user has to scroll again I want to keep my old fragment, so I want to use add instead of transaction, so the old fragment is still in the same state when the user returns to it. Is that also the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly the same events as in an Activity, but with some differences:

[image]
([source](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html))

Answer (score 0):

The lifecycle events for a fragment are as follows:

(Fragment Launched) -> `onAttach` -> `onCreate` -> `onCreateView` -> `onActivityCreated` -> `onStart` -> `onResume` -> `onResume` -> (Fragment Now Active) -> `onPause` -> `onStop` -> `onDestroyView` -> `onDestroy` -> `onDetach` -> (Fragment destroyed)

You can read more about the lifecycle [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

I would get the database in `onCreate` and close it in `onStop`. You want to avoid putting tasks in `onDestroy` because it's better that it executes quickly.

Comment: As far as I understand onStop: Called when the activity is no longer visible to the user, because another activity has been resumed and is covering this one.

I would need to reinitiate the database afterwards, right?

Comment: The `onStop` callback is attached to the activity's `onStop` callback, however, it is also triggered if the fragment is removed or replaced.